# How to get Order Incremented id in Mage::registry in All Totals page

Tags: registry, magento-1.9

I want to get Incremented id or order id from Mage::registry 
i am doing like this but it does not work.

```
 class My_Module_Block_Order_Totals extends Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals {

            protected function _initTotals() {
            parent::_initTotals();
            $order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
            $order1 = $this->getOrder();
            $order_id = Mage::registry('order_id');
            }
    }
```

My Observer.php

```
public function myFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $mydata=$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        Mage::register('order_id' , $mydata->getIncrementId());
        //Mage::log(Mage::registry('order_id'));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on success page then you can easily get the ID like this -

```
$orderID = $this->getOrderId();
```

On other pages you can do like as follows but the above code would't work on other pages.

```
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
```